What led to Season 8 Episode 1 of My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic?
Season 8 Episode 1 of My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic shows the start of Twilight Sparkle's school. What led to this development? Was it discussed in the previous episodes/films? It seemed like a very abrupt change, and I wanted to make sure I had not missed anything.
Is it related to Stygian? Or perhaps one of the movies?

I don't understand what you mean by "what led to it".

@Valorum i.e. was it discussed in the previous episodes/films? It seemed like a very abrupt change and I wanted to make sure I had not missed anything.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Retool

There are two ways to approach this.
Lore wise, Twilight just had the idea on the spot after seeing that the Cutie Map had expanded.

Twilight Sparkle: No. I mean, the world is filled with so many different creatures who know nothing about friendship. We need help if we're gonna teach them all about friendship. Lots of help.
Rarity: Perhaps. But where does one go to learn about friendship?
Twilight Sparkle: Here! They can all go here! Because we're gonna open a school!
source: Season 8 Episode 1 - School Daze

This is somehow believable if you take in account Twilight own insecurity and her extreme idealization of Celestia as the perfect mentor. After all, by opening a school Twily is just doing what Celestia did with her "School for Gifted Unicorns", a place that was the turning point for Twilight own life as seen in Season 1 Episode 23 - The Cutie Mark Chronicles (and coincidentally one of the causes of at least two other characters villain arc...).
Out of lore, the explanation is probably much simpler: Hasbro needed a new toy to sell. To quote Phoebe:

source
